# remote debugging through terminal server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a .NET application running in the target machine. the problem is that, it's firewalled and can't be accessed directly through the developer network. There's a terminal server connected in between this were it acts as a bridge between these two networks. I want to debug from my developer PC to the target PC using remote debugging facilities in Visual Studio/WinDBG. Is it possible?[Screenshot http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9767/connectiono.png](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9767/connectiono.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any channeling mechanism that can go through RDP, but perhaps the following setting can be a bearable workaround:

1. Place WinDbg or NTSD on the target system, so they can act as the remote debugging agent.
2. Place WinDbg on the terminal server, and have it connect to the target system using remote debugging.
3. Use RDP's drive mapping to let the terminal server have access to the sources on the developer PC, and configure WinDbg to use those sources.

This is far from ideal - no doubt the easiest way to debug is on the dev machine. However, it saves you from moving source files around, and since WinDbg is portable, you don't have to do heavy installations on a non-dev machine.